# Catch "Tcl Interpreter Error"

Tags: tcl

Is there any way to catch the global "Tcl Interpreter Error"? For example I would like to automatically store in some file the message that follows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core command for trapping any kind of error thrown by Tcl is [`catch`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/catch.htm). It takes at least one argument, a script to evaluate, and returns the result code from evaluating that script. The result code is `1` when an error occurs, `0` when there was no error, and a bunch of other things in other cases (indicating other types of usually-non-error exception). The `catch` also takes an optional argument that names a variable into which to write the result of evaluating the script *or* the error message. The global variable `errorInfo` will contain the stack trace in the case of an error (or from 8.5 onwards you can get the interpreter state dictionary with a further variable name passed to `catch`).

To trap an error in some script “foo.tcl”, you would use code like this:

```
if {[catch {source foo.tcl} msg]} {
    puts "I got an error: $msg"
    puts "The stack trace was this:\n$errorInfo"
}
```

It's up to you to work out how to write that out to a file if you want. (I use this technique with an outer script that implements a carefully tested error trap and which loads  an inner script that does the real work. I find it works well. Or you can call procedures in that “caught” script. Up to you really; Tcl should make *all* errors trappable, and there are very few conditions which slip through.)

---

The other route that errors can be reported is via [`bgerror`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/bgerror.htm), which is called to handle errors that occur during event processing. It's a procedure you can write your own version of; it will be given a single argument when called that is the error message, and will have the global `errorInfo` set correctly when called:

```
proc bgerror {msg} {
    global errorInfo
    puts "I got an error in an event: $msg"
    puts "The stack trace was this:\n$errorInfo"
}
```

If there is no implementation of `bgerror` defined, the stack trace is just written to the `stderr` channel. If you're using the Tk package, an implementation of `bgerror` is provided which pops up a dialog box describing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the bgerror or interp bgerror commands.

Read the [bgerror](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/bgerror.htm) documentation, it has a simple example.

Comment: Good suggestion. But it doesn't work. :( I still get `Tcl Interpreter Error: can't read "on1": no such variable` of sorts on the terminal, but not in the function.